# Alpha component for object._colors in XTK

Tags: xtk

Is it possible to have Alpha component for object._colors ?

```
    var object = new X.object();
    var c = object._colors;

    var color = new Array(4);
    c.add(color[0], color[1], color[2], color[4]);//Is this Allowed ..?
```

I am having the R,G,B,A values in color. where R= Red, G= Green, B= Blue and A = transparency component.

Is it possible to allow transparency/Alpha component ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

X.object has an attribute "opacity" (varying between 0 and 1) implemented in the mixin "displayable", so to use it from inside the framework use object._opacity and from outside "object.opacity=;" or "var myvar = object.opacity;" (respectively the setter and getter for opacity).

Other property you can use is object._visible (boolean) to choose if you display it or not.

Ricola3D

Comment: The attribute 'opacity' is applied to the whole object. But i need to specify the alpha component of the color for each vertices.

Comment: Ah ok ! I think it will require a few changes in the framework code, let's see what's Haehn's opinion.